# When should I expect to see payroll details on ird.govt.nz?

Tags: income-tax, new-zealand

My daughter had two jobs in the second half of last year. The first was a very dodgy outfit that extended her shifts without notice, wouldn't let her take her breaks, and, I suspect, hasn't paid any payroll tax or Kiwisaver contributions.

Over the holidays we checked her "My Income" page on ird.govt.nz. The payroll details for the second employer are there for November, but not yet for December. There are no details yet for the first employer, that she started working for in September.

How long should we wait before reporting the first employer to the IRD?